# ILNumerics ILSurface Adjust Z values

Tags: ilnumerics

Is there a way to manipulate the range of Z values for a Surface plot in a way that can preserve the original values so I can create a range slider with a min and max values from the GetLimits() method and then update the data array Z values so I can set new limits but move the slides back and forth to adjust the min/max Z value and see the plot adjust as I do it?

Given this code

```
            ILArray<float> tempArray = ILMath.tosingle(myDoubleArray);

            dataArray.a = tempArray;

            var plotCube = ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>();
            var surface =  plotCube.First<ILFastSurface>();

            surface.Update(Z: dataArray, colormap: new ILColormap(ILColormaps.ILNumerics));
            ilPanel1.Refresh();
```

The MinValue and MaxValue controls are initialized like this.

```
            float maxZ, minZ;
            dataArray.GetLimits(out minZ, out maxZ);
            var zRange = maxZ - minZ;

            MinValue.Maximum = (decimal)maxZ;
            MinValue.Minimum = (decimal)minZ;
            MinValue.Value = (decimal)minZ;

            MaxValue.Maximum = (decimal)maxZ;
            MaxValue.Minimum = (decimal)minZ;
            MaxValue.Value = (decimal)maxZ;
```

I want to be able to manipulate the Z values in the array like this

```
        dataArray[dataArray < (float)MinValue.Value] = (float)MinValue.Value;
        dataArray[dataArray > (float)MaxValue.Value] = (float)MaxValue.Value;

        var plotCube = ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>();
        var surface = plotCube.First<ILFastSurface>();

        surface.Update(Z: dataArray, colormap: new ILColormap(ILColormaps.ILNumerics));
        ilPanel1.Refresh();
```

The issue is that dataArray is being changed with new min/max values.   How can I restore dataArray if you want to change back to a larger min/max?   Do I just clone dataArray and use that to change the plot?  Or is there a feature of ILArray that tracks changes and can restore the array?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what you want to achieve for a while now. But no luck. Could you try to reformulate the question please? You might give an example of what you have and which result you expect.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I found a way to make this work.  not sure if it is the best or correct way.  I am able to clone the array to a temporary array  ILArray<float> tempArray = dataArray.C;    and then make the min/max changes to the temp array and just pass the temp array to the update  surface.Update(Z: tempArray);

Comment: It would be nicer if you could just edit the min/max values of the colorbar and it would update the surface without it updating the original data.

Comment: Do you want to change the vertices Z positions or the colors of the grid points or the colors data range? Right now you seem to change the z values. But how does this relate to the colorbar?

Comment: It might help to say that I do not display Axis or Labels for my Plot Cube. I hide them.  So the only source of data is the colobar values.  They display the Z height range.  I want the ability to "flatten" the Z heights to normalize the height and make the range be more realistic instead of the true values of the original data.  For example I might want to display my surface in a range of -60 to 120nm  but the acutal data in my data array is -800 to 600nm because of some stray values that cause the range to be more extream.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is to use a temporary array and clone the original array and then normalize the temporary array and update the surface with it.

```
        float min = surface.GetRangeMinValue(AxisNames.CAxis) + minOffs;
        float max = surface.GetRangeMaxValue(AxisNames.CAxis) + maxOffs;

         ILArray<float> tempArray = _dataArray.C;
        tempArray[tempArray < min] = min;
        tempArray[tempArray > max] = max;

        surface.Update(Z: tempArray);
```

_dataArray is a static property loaded once with the original data.  Any updates are done with the code above